# AccordionPanel containing data tables with selectionMode="multiple"

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

**XHTML file:**

```
    <p:tab title="firstTab" id="FT">

        <p:dataTable var="..." value="#{...}" id="firstTable" selectionMode="multiple"
        selection="#{myController.selectedRows}">
            <p:column>...</p:column>
            <p:column>...</p:column>
            <p:commandButton value="View" action="#myController.viewSelected}"/>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab title="secondTab" id="ST">

        <p:dataTable var="..." value="#{...}" id="secondTable" selectionMode="multiple"
        selection="#{myController.selectedRows}">
            <p:column>...</p:column>
            <p:column>...</p:column>
            <p:commandButton value="View" action="#myController.viewSelected}"/>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>
```

**Managed Bean:**

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyController{
    MyObject[] selectedRows;
        //get+set

    public void viewSelected(){
        System.out.println(selectedRows.length)
    }
}
```

The console output varies. Sometimes the output is *0* but usually the selectedRows content gets messed up. The result is mixed if i have selections in both dataTable-s and press one of the two commandButton-s. I'm guessing that this is happening because there isn't a specific id for the buttons or maybe i should use different business attributes for every dataTable. Which is the correct solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What PF version are you using?

Also if that `commandButton` isn't inside a column or anything else, what's the deal with him?
If you want to be a dataTable footer you have to do like this:

```
<f:facet name="footer"> 
   <p:commandButton value="View" action="#myController.viewSelected}"/>
</facet>
```

The way you are assigning the selected rows from both dataTables to the same array, I'd say this isn't a good practice, in fact I have never seen something like this! What's point? Even you would like to have two dataTables with the same records, you should at least assign a `different array/list` for selected records in each table and put them in `different forms` if you don't want to trigger both events on pressing just a commandButton...